# Navigate to specific tab panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to design an asp:HyperLink that, when clicked, will redirect the user to a control with several ajax:TabPanels. Is there a way I can navigate to a specific TabPanel using the NavigateURL property of my HyperLink?

Comment: Why are you using ajax control toolkit in the first place?This is 2016, use bootstrap to display a tab control

Comment: ajax control toolkit was the existing code. i was hoping to avoid rewriting code.